# gsutil cp command copies entire directory path (on Windows) - bug?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cp, gsutil

I am having a problem where gsutil does not seem to follow the behavior described in the documentation (at least in Windows). The documentation states:

---

When performing recursive directory copies, object names are constructed that mirror the source directory structure starting at the point of recursive processing. For example, the command:

```
gsutil cp -R dir1/dir2 gs://my_bucket
```

will create objects named like `gs://my_bucket/dir2/a/b/c`, assuming `dir1/dir2` contains the file `a/b/c`.

---

However, in practice I have found that it will create objects named:

```
gs://my_bucket/dir1/dir2/a/b/c
```

ie, it copies the **entire** directory path stated in the `gsutil` command, rather than "starting at the point of recursive processing" (dir2) as stated in the documentation.

Am I missing/misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 15):

I noticed the same behavior when using the `gsutil cp -R` command with a similar directory structure.  In order to copy the desired directory from within the 'dir2' level I used the command: `gsutil rsync -r dir1/dir2 gs://mybucket`

Comment: Great just what I been looking for!

Comment: Thanks @JoshFire311